# Put lambda in VPC and subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have `lambda` function which needs to access `RDS` in isolated private subnet.

And `lambda` function also need to access internet endpoint and be invoked from internet.

In this case,

- put `lambda` in private subnet (with Nat gateway)
- `lambda` can access internet from nat gateway

However ,,, is it possible to invoke `lambda` function in private subnet from internet?

(I can set API gateway to the lambda in private subnet?)

Comment: The Lambda service [data plane](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/security-overview-aws-lambda/lambda-executions.html) can allocate your Lambda environment and execute your Lambda function regardless of its network configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "However ,,, is it possible to invoke lambda function in private
> subnet from internet?"

Yes, you always invoke Lambda from the AWS API, which is on the public Internet. Then AWS creates an instance of your Lambda function to handle the invocation. You never make a direct network connection to a Lambda function. It doesn't matter if your Lambda function is configured to run inside your VPC, you still invoke it the same way.

Comment: Thank you!! that's very cool and good news for me. It's very understandable.